# Why Twitter Timeline is not getting loaded in based on variable in Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to load the twitter timeline of multiple accounts based on the route. For example, if someone requests a specific page, twitter timeline for a specific account is loaded on the page.

I tried using one plugin called `vue-tweet-embed` but it was not working at all, So, I tried the old way. I included twitter's `widgets.js` in my main HTML file and tried including timeline with static code as given below.

**Static Code**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Google</a>
```

Now, I want to show Twitter timeline of multiple accounts based on the variable. My variable is a property of one object, So, Here is the code I am trying to use. Note that above given static code works even in a Vue component.

**Dynamic Code**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500px" v-if="isLoading===false" :href="'https://twitter.com/'+service.twitter_handle+'?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'"></a>
```

But the dynamic one is not working. I checked with inspect element and the markup being generated by the code is perfectly fine. But it is showing nothing. It is not loading a twitter timeline when the code is dynamic.

Here's the **generated markup**:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <a data-height="500px" href="https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-timeline"></a>
</div>
```

I don't know what's wrong, Trying to solve this since last 3 hours but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share the markup generated?

Comment: @adiga, Here you go -> https://pastebin.com/WCFapRBa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tell the Twitter JavaScript library to reload your widgets by calling [twttr.widgets.load()](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization) wrapped in $nextTick after changing the twitter_handle property.

```
$nextTick(function () { twttr.widgets.load(); });
```

With $nextTick you make sure that Vue rendered the HTML with all changes before executing the code.

Comment: 1. I made sure that the service object and the twitter_handle property are reactive and the correct url is inserted into the href attribute. 100%

Comment: 2. Tried right now, Told Twitter Javascript library to reload widgets using "twttr.widgets.load()" after making sure that the service object and twitter_handle are loaded first to create a desired markup. But it's still not working.

Comment: Alright then try reloading twitter widgets as follows `$nextTick(function () { twttr.widgets.load() });` after changing the twitter_handle property.

Comment: If it still does not work, you can try binding the url as key to the a tag so that a new tag gets created every time the url changes: `<a ... :key="service.twitter_handle">`. Try combining this change with reloading the widgets.

Comment: $nextTick did the job! Thanks a lot for letting me know about this. Thanks! Please add this to the answer, I am verifying the answer.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I had to add `:key` as @Stee suggested + `$nextTick`